# PocketSphinx android demo runtime exception

Tags: java, android, offline, voice-recognition, pocketsphinx-android

I downloaded the source code of pocket sphinx demo. I'm trying to run it but it is throwing a runtime exception. I've posted the logcat of my code.

```
09-09 11:45:38.980: I/System.out(7912): Sending WAIT chunk
09-09 11:45:38.980: W/ActivityThread(7912): Application edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
09-09 11:45:39.030: I/dalvikvm(7912): Debugger is active
09-09 11:45:39.210: I/System.out(7912): Debugger has connected
09-09 11:45:39.210: I/System.out(7912): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-09 11:45:39.400: I/System.out(7912): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-09 11:45:39.600: I/System.out(7912): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-09 11:45:39.810: I/System.out(7912): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-09 11:45:40.000: I/System.out(7912): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-09 11:45:40.210: I/System.out(7912): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-09 11:45:40.400: I/System.out(7912): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-09 11:45:40.600: I/System.out(7912): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-09 11:45:40.810: I/System.out(7912): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-09 11:45:41.010: I/System.out(7912): debugger has settled (1359)
09-09 11:45:41.930: D/dalvikvm(7912): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-09 11:45:48.960: I/dalvikvm(7912): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
09-09 11:45:48.960: D/dalvikvm(7912): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
09-09 11:45:48.960: I/dalvikvm(7912): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-09 11:45:52.310: D/dalvikvm(7912): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 44K, 49% free 2778K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 26ms
09-09 11:45:58.770: D/CLIPBOARD(7912): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
09-09 11:46:05.860: D/dalvikvm(7912): GC_CONCURRENT freed 366K, 50% free 2845K/5639K, external 7K/1286K, paused 2ms+3ms
09-09 11:46:05.870: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/grammar/menu.gram: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:05.870: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/grammar/digits.gram: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:05.880: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/lm/3015.lm: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:05.890: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/hmm/en-us/noisedict: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:05.900: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/hmm/en-us/mixture_weights: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:05.900: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/hmm/en-us/means: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:05.900: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/hmm/en-us/variances: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:05.900: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/hmm/en-us/transition_matrices: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:05.910: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/dict/5497.dic: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:05.910: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/hmm/en-us/feature_transform: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:05.910: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/hmm/en-us/mdef: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:05.910: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/hmm/en-us/feat.params: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:05.910: I/Assets(7912): Skipping asset models/hmm/en-us/README: checksums are equal
09-09 11:46:15.670: D/dalvikvm(7912): Trying to load lib /data/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so 0x4051cbd0
09-09 11:46:15.680: D/dalvikvm(7912): Added shared lib /data/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so 0x4051cbd0
09-09 11:46:15.680: D/dalvikvm(7912): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so 0x4051cbd0, skipping init
09-09 11:46:15.680: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: cmd_ln.c(696): Parsing command line:
09-09 11:46:15.680: I/cmusphinx(7912): Current configuration:
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: cmd_ln.c(696): Parsing command line:
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): \
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912):  
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): -nfilt 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): 25 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): \
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912):  
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): -lowerf 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): 130 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): \
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912):  
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): -upperf 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): 6800 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): \
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912):  
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): -transform 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): dct 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): \
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912):  
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): -lifter 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): 22 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): \
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912):  
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): -feat 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): 1s_c_d_dd 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): \
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912):  
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): -agc 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): none 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): \
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912):  
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): -cmn 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): current 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): \
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912):  
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): -varnorm 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): no 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): \
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912):  
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): -cmninit 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): 40 
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): Current configuration:
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: acmod.c(251): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/hmm/en-us/feat.params
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
09-09 11:46:31.640: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: acmod.c(160): Reading linear feature transformation from /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/hmm/en-us/feature_transform
09-09 11:46:31.650: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: mdef.c(517): Reading model definition: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/hmm/en-us/mdef
09-09 11:46:33.430: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: bin_mdef.c(181): Allocating 173954 * 8 bytes (1359 KiB) for CD tree
09-09 11:46:33.570: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: tmat.c(206): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/hmm/en-us/transition_matrices
09-09 11:46:33.570: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: acmod.c(123): Attempting to use SCHMM computation module
09-09 11:46:33.570: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/hmm/en-us/means
09-09 11:46:35.110: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 6138 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
09-09 11:46:35.110: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  32x32
09-09 11:46:35.110: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/hmm/en-us/variances
09-09 11:46:36.890: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 6138 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
09-09 11:46:36.900: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  32x32
09-09 11:46:38.920: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 768 variance values floored
09-09 11:46:38.950: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: acmod.c(125): Attempting to use PTHMM computation module
09-09 11:46:38.960: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/hmm/en-us/means
09-09 11:46:40.140: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 6138 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
09-09 11:46:40.140: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  32x32
09-09 11:46:40.140: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/hmm/en-us/variances
09-09 11:46:40.820: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 6138 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
09-09 11:46:40.820: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  32x32
09-09 11:46:42.850: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 768 variance values floored
09-09 11:46:42.850: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ptm_mgau.c(792): Number of codebooks exceeds 256: 6138
09-09 11:46:42.860: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: acmod.c(127): Falling back to general multi-stream GMM computation
09-09 11:46:42.860: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/hmm/en-us/means
09-09 11:46:43.280: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 6138 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
09-09 11:46:43.280: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  32x32
09-09 11:46:43.280: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/hmm/en-us/variances
09-09 11:46:43.480: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 6138 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
09-09 11:46:43.480: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  32x32
09-09 11:46:45.540: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 768 variance values floored
09-09 11:46:45.550: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_senone.c(149): Reading senone mixture weights: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/hmm/en-us/mixture_weights
09-09 11:46:45.550: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_senone.c(200): Truncating senone logs3(pdf) values by 10 bits
09-09 11:46:45.550: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_senone.c(207): Not transposing mixture weights in memory
09-09 11:46:45.610: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_senone.c(268): Read mixture weights for 6138 senones: 1 features x 32 codewords
09-09 11:46:45.610: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_senone.c(320): Mapping senones to individual codebooks
09-09 11:46:45.610: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ms_mgau.c(141): The value of topn: 4
09-09 11:46:45.620: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 4181 * 20 bytes (81 KiB) for word entries
09-09 11:46:45.620: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: dict.c(333): Reading main dictionary: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/dict/5497.dic
09-09 11:46:45.620: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: dict.c(213): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
09-09 11:46:45.620: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: dict.c(336): 76 words read
09-09 11:46:45.620: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: dict.c(342): Reading filler dictionary: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/hmm/en-us/noisedict
09-09 11:46:45.620: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: dict.c(213): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
09-09 11:46:45.620: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: dict.c(345): 9 words read
09-09 11:46:45.620: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
09-09 11:46:45.620: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 46^3 * 2 bytes (190 KiB) for word-initial triphones
09-09 11:46:45.650: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 25576 bytes (24 KiB) for word-final triphones
09-09 11:46:45.650: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 25576 bytes (24 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
09-09 11:46:59.750: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: kws_search.c(417): KWS(beam: -1080, plp: -23, default threshold -450)
09-09 11:46:59.750: E/cmusphinx(7912): ERROR: "kws_search.c", line 158: The word 'taking' is missing in the dictionary
09-09 11:47:07.390: I/SpeechRecognizer(7912): Load JSGF /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/grammar/menu.gram
09-09 11:47:07.400: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: jsgf.c(664): Defined rule: PUBLIC <menu.item>
09-09 11:47:07.400: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: fsg_model.c(215): Computing transitive closure for null transitions
09-09 11:47:07.400: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: fsg_model.c(277): 0 null transitions added
09-09 11:47:07.400: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: fsg_search.c(227): FSG(beam: -1080, pbeam: -1080, wbeam: -634; wip: -26, pip: 0)
09-09 11:47:07.400: E/cmusphinx(7912): ERROR: "fsg_search.c", line 142: The word 'forecast' is missing in the dictionary
09-09 11:47:26.240: I/SpeechRecognizer(7912): Load JSGF /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/grammar/digits.gram
09-09 11:47:26.240: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: jsgf.c(664): Defined rule: <digits.digit>
09-09 11:47:26.250: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: jsgf.c(664): Defined rule: <digits.g00001>
09-09 11:47:26.250: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: jsgf.c(664): Defined rule: PUBLIC <digits.digits>
09-09 11:47:26.250: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: jsgf.c(381): Right recursion <digits.g00001> 2 => 0
09-09 11:47:26.250: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: fsg_model.c(215): Computing transitive closure for null transitions
09-09 11:47:26.250: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: fsg_model.c(277): 0 null transitions added
09-09 11:47:26.250: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: fsg_search.c(227): FSG(beam: -1080, pbeam: -1080, wbeam: -634; wip: -26, pip: 0)
09-09 11:47:26.250: E/cmusphinx(7912): ERROR: "fsg_search.c", line 142: The word 'nine' is missing in the dictionary
09-09 11:47:36.880: I/SpeechRecognizer(7912): Load N-gram model /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo/files/sync/models/lm/3015.lm
09-09 11:47:36.890: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(477): ngrams 1=58, 2=117, 3=140
09-09 11:47:36.890: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(135): Reading unigrams
09-09 11:47:36.890: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(516):       58 = #unigrams created
09-09 11:47:36.890: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(195): Reading bigrams
09-09 11:47:36.890: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(533):      117 = #bigrams created
09-09 11:47:36.890: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(534):       26 = #prob2 entries
09-09 11:47:36.890: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(542):       19 = #bo_wt2 entries
09-09 11:47:36.890: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(292): Reading trigrams
09-09 11:47:36.900: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(555):      140 = #trigrams created
09-09 11:47:36.900: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_model_arpa.c(556):       14 = #prob3 entries
09-09 11:47:36.900: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(99): 55 unique initial diphones
09-09 11:47:36.900: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(148): 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 11 single-phone words
09-09 11:47:36.900: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search tree
09-09 11:47:36.900: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(192): before: 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 11 single-phone words
09-09 11:47:36.900: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(326): after: max nonroot chan increased to 280
09-09 11:47:36.900: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(339): after: 55 root, 152 non-root channels, 10 single-phone words
09-09 11:47:36.900: I/cmusphinx(7912): INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(157): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
09-09 11:47:48.380: I/SpeechRecognizer(7912): Start recognition "leave"
09-09 11:49:41.350: W/dalvikvm(7912): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912): java.lang.RuntimeException: Decoder_setSearch returned -1
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.PocketSphinxJNI.Decoder_setSearch(Native Method)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Decoder.setSearch(Unknown Source)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer.startListening(Unknown Source)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PocketSphinxActivity.switchSearch(PocketSphinxActivity.java:143)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PocketSphinxActivity.access$1(PocketSphinxActivity.java:141)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PocketSphinxActivity$1.onPostExecute(PocketSphinxActivity.java:102)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PocketSphinxActivity$1.onPostExecute(PocketSphinxActivity.java:1)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3770)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
09-09 11:49:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 11:49:43.580: I/dalvikvm(7912): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
09-09 11:49:43.610: I/dalvikvm(7912): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: on emulator or real device?

Comment: @Arnav M i'm debugging it on device..

Comment: Looks like you didn't just copy the code but also modified it. You made errors in your modifications. You need to describe what did you modify exactly in order to get help on the issue.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev The only modification I did is that I've included my own dictionary and models instead of the ones included in the original code.(I've now resolved the error that 'nine' and 'taking' are not in the dictionary). The app isn't recognizing anything and is crashing at the startListening() method.

Comment: Ok, provide the updated log. Ideally provide the archive of your project. You can upload it to dropbox and give here a link.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I've shared my project. Please have a look..help me out...https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sd5w6gv73rxn871/AAAM8Q9QhmU6rBPjlEgHxNCpa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You could see the following errors in the log:

```
09-09 11:47:26.250: E/cmusphinx(7912): ERROR: "fsg_search.c", line 142: The word 'nine' is missing in the dictionary
09-09 11:46:59.750: E/cmusphinx(7912): ERROR: "kws_search.c", line 158: The word 'taking' is missing in the dictionary
```

Looks like your dictionary is incompatible with your changes. You need to make sure dictionary contains all required words.

And, I see you made some changes but most of them are incomplete. For example you commented the code to setup named searches in setupRecognizer but didn't change switch code, so it still tries to switch to older searches. You can try something like this, it should work:

```
package edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo;

import static android.widget.Toast.makeText;
import static edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Assets;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Hypothesis;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.RecognitionListener;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer;

public class PocketSphinxActivity extends Activity implements
        RecognitionListener {

    private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "KEYPHRASE";
    private static final String DICTATION_SEARCH = "DICTATION";

    private static final String KEYPHRASE = "MORNING";

    private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);

        // Prepare the data for UI
        captions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
        captions.put(DICTATION_SEARCH, R.string.forecast_caption);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                .setText("Preparing the recognizer");

        // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
        // so we execute it in async task

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
            @Override
            protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Assets assets = new Assets(PocketSphinxActivity.this);

                    File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();

                    setupRecognizer(assetDir);

                    recognizer.startListening(KWS_SEARCH);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return e;
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                            .setText("Failed to init recognizer " + result);
                } else {
                    switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        Log.d("Spoken text",text);

        if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE))
            switchSearch(DICTATION_SEARCH);

        else
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("");
        if (hypothesis != null) {
            String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
            makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.d("end","In end of speech");
        if (DICTATION_SEARCH.equals(recognizer.getSearchName()))
            switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
    }

    private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
        recognizer.stop();
        recognizer.startListening(searchName);
        String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(caption);
    }

    private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) {
        File modelsDir = new File(assetsDir, "models");
        recognizer = defaultSetup()
                .setAcousticModel(new File(modelsDir, "hmm/en-us"))
                .setDictionary(new File(modelsDir, "dict/5497.dic"))
                .setRawLogDir(assetsDir).setKeywordThreshold(1e-20f)
                .setFloat("-beam", 1e-30f)
                .getRecognizer();
        recognizer.addListener(this);

        // Create keyword-activation search.
        recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);

        // Create language model search.
        File languageModel = new File(modelsDir, "lm/3015.lm");
        recognizer.addNgramSearch(DICTATION_SEARCH, languageModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanka a lot. This solved the problem. Can you tell how to do a continous recognition instead of a keyword search...(i.e what to used instead of recorder.startListening(String string)..?

Comment: startListening(DICTATION_SEARCH) starts listening with lm. You need to remove KWS_SEARCH altogether then.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks a lot.
Btw.. our app size is about 00MB..(We have around 62 sentences i the corpus and 52 words in dictionary). Is this normal or are we going wrong somewhere?

Comment: You probably didn't remove some unused files from assets.

Comment: I've changed the mean and variance files (lower size) and this error is coming up.   09-10 14:20:37.019: E/cmusphinx(11594): ERROR: "ms_mgau.c", line 107: Number of streams does not match: 3 != 1

Comment: You can not replace model parts, you can only replace model as a whole.