# How to deal with errors gracefully in PocketSphinx for Android?

Tags: android, error-handling, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I have made a program with PocketSphinx for Android, but there is one problem. Sometimes I have errors such as

```
ERROR: "kws_search.c", line 164: The word 'sadfasdf' is missing in the dictionary".
```

and then the whole program crashes. I know why the error comes up, but is there a way to deal with the error gracefully? I am more concerned about having the error not crash the program as opposed to fixing the error. It seems like I have to do something in the onError(Exception e) method, but I'm not sure what.

(There's a similar question here [Handling Errors in PocketSphinx Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283242/handling-errors-in-pocketsphinx-android-app?rq=1) which says it has been handled, but mine still crashes, although I'm sure I'm just not doing something correctly in onError())

My log is as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.company.app, PID: 26044                                                                   
java.lang.RuntimeException: Decoder_setKws returned -1
```

EDIT: I think it's just a standard RuntimeException which I don't know yet how to handle - how do I deal with them?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exceptions with try/catch.