# Exception when word is missing in the dictionary

Tags: pocketsphinx-android

I tried the demo app, it works fine but when I tried to integrate my own .jsgf grammar file it is giving error when I tried same thing using .lm file for the same dictionary it is working fine .

I referred to [PocketSphinx android demo runtime exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738001/pocketsphinx-android-demo-runtime-exception) link but it didn't help me out

Following is the code snippet:

```
private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
        // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
        // of different kind and switch between them
        File modelsDir = new File(assetsDir, "models");
        mRecognizer = defaultSetup()
                .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
                .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))
                .setRawLogDir(assetsDir)
                .setKeywordThreshold(1e-10f)
                .setFloat("-beam", 1e-30f)
                .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)
                .getRecognizer();
        mRecognizer.addListener(this);
        File languageModel = new File(assetsDir, "commands_gram.gram");
        mRecognizer.addGrammarSearch(COMMANDS, languageModel);
    }
```

Following is the error

```
E/cmusphinx: ERROR: "fsg_search.c", line 141: The word 'next' is missing in the dictionary
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Process: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Decoder_setJsgfFile returned -1
at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.PocketSphinxJNI.Decoder_setJsgfFile(Native Method)
at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Decoder.setJsgfFile(Decoder.java:139)
at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer.addGrammarSearch(SpeechRecognizer.java:234)
at com.package.ui.SphinxSpeechRecognizerActivity.setupRecognizer(SphinxSpeechRecognizerActivity.java:284)
at com.package.ui.SphinxSpeechRecognizerActivity.access$400(SphinxSpeechRecognizerActivity.java:29)
at com.package.ui.SphinxSpeechRecognizerActivity$3.doInBackground(SphinxSpeechRecognizerActivity.java:239)
at com.package.ui.SphinxSpeechRecognizerActivity$3.doInBackground(SphinxSpeechRecognizerActivity.java:233)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Also I realized that any .jsgf grammar file I am using it is not detecting the last word from the dictionary. before it was working fine after I changed to my own .jsgf grammar file it is giving exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
E/cmusphinx: ERROR: "fsg_search.c", line 141: The word 'next' is missing in the dictionary
```

tells you need to add the word 'next' to the dictionary. You used this word in your JSGF grammar, but it was missing in the dictionary. Words are case-sensitive, so you need to make sure you use proper case.

Comment: I have this word in dictionary, but still it is giving this error. I have build the dictionary using the Sphinx knowledge base generator [lmtool.3a], which by default is giving words and its phonemes in Uppercase. Do I have to specifically convert the dictionary words in lowercase in that case?

Comment: The thing is I had to convert all the dictionary words in lowercase myself then only it worked, but this becomes cumbersome if you have large set of words

Answer (score 1):

I maybe know your problem.
Your have to make the grammar in correct form,like your space and tab.
I suggest you checking your grammar for block or tab.
Sorry my poor English.