# Decoder_setSearch returned -1 exception

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I recently checked out PocketSphinx powered by CMUSphinx for Android found here: https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo. I've modified it a little bit to play around and see what I could do.

```
public class PocketSphinxActivity extends Activity implements
    RecognitionListener {

/* Named searches allow to quickly reconfigure the decoder */
private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";
private static final String OVER_COMMAND = "overshield";
private static final String INVISIBLE_COMMAND = "invis";
private static final String POWER_COMMAND = "power";
private static final String MENU_SEARCH = "menu";

/* Keyword we are looking for to activate menu */
private static final String KEYPHRASE = "ready coach";
private boolean isGameStarted = false;

/* Used to handle permission request */
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;

private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);

    // Prepare the data for UI
    captions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
    captions.put(MENU_SEARCH, R.string.menu_caption);
    captions.put(INVISIBLE_COMMAND, R.string.invis_caption);
    captions.put(OVER_COMMAND, R.string.os_caption);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
            .setText("Preparing the recognizer");

    // Check if user has given permission to record audio
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
        return;
    }
    runRecognizerSetup();
}

private void runRecognizerSetup() {
    // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
    // so we execute it in async task
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Assets assets = new Assets(PocketSphinxActivity.this);
                File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                setupRecognizer(assetDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
            if (result != null) {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                        .setText("Failed to init recognizer " + result);
            } else {
                switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            runRecognizerSetup();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (recognizer != null) {
        recognizer.cancel();
        recognizer.shutdown();
    }
}

/**
 * In partial result we get quick updates about current hypothesis. In
 * keyword spotting mode we can react here, in other modes we need to wait
 * for final result in onResult.
 */
@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis == null)
        return;

    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
    if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE))
        switchSearch(MENU_SEARCH);
        //Invisible Mentioned
    else if (text.equals(INVISIBLE_COMMAND))
        switchSearch(INVISIBLE_COMMAND);
        //Over Mentioned
    else if (text.equals(OVER_COMMAND))
        switchSearch(OVER_COMMAND);
    else if (text.equals(POWER_COMMAND))
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);
    else
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);
}

/**
 * This callback is called when we stop the recognizer.
 */
@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("");
    if (hypothesis != null) {
        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
}

/**
 * We stop recognizer here to get a final result
 */
@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    if (!recognizer.getSearchName().equals(KWS_SEARCH))
        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
}

private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
    recognizer.stop();

    // If we are not spotting, start listening with timeout (10000 ms or 10 seconds).
    if (searchName.equals(KEYPHRASE)) {
        isGameStarted = true;
        startTimer();

    } else {

        if (isGameStarted)
            recognizer.startListening(searchName);
        else
            recognizer.startListening(searchName, 10000);

        String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(caption);
    }
}

private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
    // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
    // of different kind and switch between them

    recognizer = SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
            .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))

            //            .setRawLogDir(assetsDir) // To disable logging of raw audio comment out this call (takes a lot of space on the device)

            .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);

    // Create keyword-activation search.
    recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);

    // Create grammar-based search for selection between demos
    File menuGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "menu.gram");
    recognizer.addGrammarSearch(MENU_SEARCH, menuGrammar);
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception error) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(error.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void onTimeout() {
    switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
}

public void startTimer() {
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                    .setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            isGameStarted = false;
            // mTextField.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

Everything works fine when I load it up but I have been experimenting and trying to change the words that it recognizes. It seems to recognize "stop" fine but the other ones are giving me problems. Right now I have the following Grammer setup:

```
#JSGF V1.0;

grammar menu;
```

public  = (invis | invisible | overshield | stop | power | close);

I've also added the custom words to my dictionary file just to make sure they were in there.

**Here is the error log i'm getting, what else do I need to do to incorporate these words into my project?**

```
11-22 23:17:02.812 6856-6856/edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx I/SpeechRecognizer: Stop recognition
11-22 23:17:02.812 6856-6856/edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx I/SpeechRecognizer: Start recognition "overshield"
11-22 23:17:02.812 6856-6856/edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-22 23:17:02.812 6856-6856/edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx, PID: 6856
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Decoder_setSearch returned -1
                                                                               at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.PocketSphinxJNI.Decoder_setSearch(Native Method)
                                                                               at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Decoder.setSearch(Decoder.java:181)
                                                                               at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer.startListening(SpeechRecognizer.java:141)
                                                                               at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PocketSphinxActivity.switchSearch(PocketSphinxActivity.java:215)
                                                                               at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PocketSphinxActivity.onPartialResult(PocketSphinxActivity.java:170)
                                                                               at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer$ResultEvent.execute(SpeechRecognizer.java:427)
                                                                               at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer$RecognitionEvent.run(SpeechRecognizer.java:391)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)


                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738001/pocketsphinx-android-demo-runtime-exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confused "search" and a "command". You have added two searches - `KWS_SEARCH` and `MENU_SEARCH`, you can switch between them. `MENU_SEARCH` more properly should be called `COMMAND_SEARCH`. You can not switch to `OVER_COMMAND` because it is a command not a search and this is what exception tells you. You need to perform actions and switch to `KWS_SEARCH` instead.

Your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis == null)
        return;

    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
    if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE))
        switchSearch(MENU_SEARCH);
}


@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis == null) 
       return;

    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
    if (text.equals(OVER_COMMAND)) {
        // RUN ACTIONS FOR OVER_COMMAND_HERE
    }
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    if (!recognizer.getSearchName().equals(KWS_SEARCH))
        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Nikolay, this answer was detailed and now I've been able to really get going with this! Appreciate the clarification!